# Databricks -> Snowflake: SQL compilation error: Stage: 'XYZ' cannot be a temporary stage in the pipe definition

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, databricks, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-databricks

I try to materialize stream from Databricks into Snowflake table:

parsedStream
  .writeStream
    .outputMode("append")
    .options(options)
    .option("dbtable", "test_table")
    .option("streaming_stage","test_stage")
    .option("checkpointLocation","/demo-checkpoints")
    .format("snowflake")
    .start()

options contains all the details necessary to authenticate to snowflake and this part works. 
I checked both precreated stage and non-existing stage so that Databricks would create temporal stage (and this is how it is supposed to be working).

I get the following error:
**net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: SQL compilation error: Stage: 'test_stage' cannot be a temporary stage in the pipe definition.**

```
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeUtil.checkErrorAndThrowExceptionSub(SnowflakeUtil.java:135)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeUtil.checkErrorAndThrowException(SnowflakeUtil.java:60)
at net.snowflake.client.core.StmtUtil.pollForOutput(StmtUtil.java:503)
at net.snowflake.client.core.StmtUtil.execute(StmtUtil.java:370)
at net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.executeHelper(SFStatement.java:474)
at net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.executeQueryInternal(SFStatement.java:230)
at net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.executeQuery(SFStatement.java:172)
at net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.execute(SFStatement.java:663)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeStatementV1.executeQueryInternal(SnowflakeStatementV1.java:161)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakePreparedStatementV1.executeQuery(SnowflakePreparedStatementV1.java:153)
at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.JDBCWrapper$$anonfun$executePreparedQueryInterruptibly$1.apply(SnowflakeJDBCWrapper.scala:257)
at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.JDBCWrapper$$anonfun$executePreparedQueryInterruptibly$1.apply(SnowflakeJDBCWrapper.scala:255)
at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.JDBCWrapper$$anonfun$2.apply(SnowflakeJDBCWrapper.scala:292)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

import net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.Utils.SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME
res17: org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery = org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamingQueryWrapper@1f36b6a9

Any ideas?

Comment: Spark Streaming with Snowflake is not GA at the moment. Do you have preview access to the feature? Have you tested a simple Spark Streaming app into Snowflake?

Answer (score 0):

Spark Streaming (using the function *writeStream*) with Snowflake is currently not generally available as a feature. You might want to rewrite your application to use the currently available Spark connector (which does not support Structured Streaming).

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/spark-connector.html